# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when getting file from PicturesLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to send a video taken from gallery (Picture folder) and sending it to my server in multipart.

For this, I am using the Isolated Storage and trying to getting the file from my pictures folder this way:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()){
....
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
string contentType = GetMimeType(fileName);
StorageFolder folder;
if (path.IndexOf("Pictures", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
  folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
  Debug.WriteLine("folder: " + folder.Name);
 }
...
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);
...
```

on the last line code I am getting such exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>d__19.MoveNext()
```

Please consider those values:

path:: C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20150708_001.mp4

folder: Pictures

fileName: WP_20150708_001.mp4

I also tried to send the path but it gave me this exception:

`System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.\r\n`

Why it does not find my file which is in my phone?

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending `path` to `GetFileAsync` instead of `fileName`?  Or at least you need the relative path which needs to include the "Camera Roll" sub directory.

Comment: @juharr please how to use the relative path?

Comment: I think the security model of windows phone forbids that you manually access files. You need to let the user choose the file with a picker

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do here? I updated my answer to provide some more background. Also, there's also no need for `IsolatedStorageFile` in this scenario, so it's not clear why it is in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is strange since you start with a `path` (how did you get that?) and then make an assumption about which library that points to, and then try to open a `StorageFile` based on splitting the filename from the path; why not just create the `StorageFile` directly from the `path`?

But you should **never** permanently store the string path to a `StorageFile` since it can change if the user moves the app or content to / from an SD card, etc. Hard-coding (or persisting) paths is a sure-fire way to have an app that won't work (or will crash) if the user ever changes where stuff is stored on their device.

I've added a comment above asking to better explain what exactly you're trying to do, and knowing that can help provide a better solution.

Comment: Torr, actually it works just changing to folder, I did not consider "Camera Roll" (C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\) while  KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary is this C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\

Comment: I misread the original question due to use of IsolatedStorageFile and System.IO.